# How to get the proper position of a SVG element using Snap SVG - getBBox()

Tags: svg, snap.svg

We're trying to get the position of a svg element using getbbox().

For example, we have an elementLogo at x y = 484, 247.

When I use this:

```
var logoSnapNew = Snap(elementLogo); var cBoxLogoNew = logoSnapNew.getBBox();
```

it returns 247, 117 instead and the elementLogo is placed a different location. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: please edit the question to contain a [mcve].

Comment: We need to at least see the elementLogo.